# SQL Server : select used multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select

I need a query to classify each record from a table based on a given description. For example, if the description contains 'CABL' the classification will be 'Cable', if it contains 'SLEV' then will be 'Slev', if it contains 'TERM' then will be 'Terminal', if it contains 'MULTI' then will be 'Multiconductor' and so on with many others classifications.

It works like this:

```
DESCRIPTION: CABL 150C TXL 0.500 BLU LT   XLPE THIN
CLASSIFICATION: Cable

DESCRIPTION: SLEV     ID=0.24  OD=0.34 L=1.04 CLR
CLASSIFICATION: Slev

DESCRIPTION: TERM 6 F 6.3 DFK AG
CLASSIFICATION: Terminal

DESCRIPTION: CABL  0.500 BLK      MULTICONDUCTOR
CLASSIFICATION: Multiconductor
```

As you can see the problem begins when the description contains more than one 'key word' on it; in the fourth example there are two keywords on the description ('CABL' and 'MULTI') but the correct classification is 'Multiconductor'.

I'm working on a query using CASE and it looks like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN Descrip LIKE 'CABL%'
         AND Descrip NOT LIKE '%MULTI%'
         AND Descrip NOT LIKE '%SLEV%' 
       THEN 'CABLE'

    WHEN Descrip LIKE '%SEAL%'
         AND Descrip NOT LIKE '%CONN%'
         AND Descrip NOT LIKE '%LOCK%'
         AND Descrip NOT LIKE '%TERM%'  
        THEN 'SEAL'
END AS Commodity
```

The query will work but is going to be a big one and I was thinking in use LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOINs to select all the classifications and then segregate them, the problem is that I need to make the SELECT sentence every time I'm going to need it so I was wondering if there is a form to put the SELECT 'inside' a variable and only do the joins using them.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Descrip LIKE 'CABL%' AS cable_selection
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Descrip LIKE '%MULTI%' AS multi_selection
```

It is just something I'm thinking on, if you know another way to do this it will help too.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the description has multiple keywords, how do you know which one of them is the correct classification ?

Comment: There is something like a priority system/weights as serverSentinel and Gordon Linoff just suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a table instead of canned select statements.

```
use tempdb; 
create table DescriptionTable (
    [desc] varchar( 50 ), 
    class varchar( 20 )
)
go

insert into DescriptionTable ( [desc] ) values 
    ('CABL 150C TXL 0.500 BLU LT   XLPE THIN'), 
    ('SLEV     ID=0.24  OD=0.34 L=1.04 CLR'),
    ('TERM 6 F 6.3 DFK AG'),
    ('CABL  0.500 BLK      MULTICONDUCTOR' )


create table #classMap (
    keyWord varchar( 20 ), 
    classification varchar( 20 ),
    weight int
)

insert into #classMap ( keyWord, classification, weight ) values 
    ( 'CABL%', 'CABLE', 1 ), 
    ( '%SLEV%', 'SLEV', 2  ),
    ( '%TERM%', 'TERMINAL', 3  ),
    ( '%MULTICONDUCTOR', 'Multiconductor', 4 ) 

;;with BestWeight as (
    select top 1 with ties [desc], classification
    from DescriptionTable 
    join #classMap 
        on [desc] like keyWord
    order by ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by [desc] order by weight desc )
)
select * from BestWeight;

drop table #classMap;
```

This results in:

```
desc    classification  weight
CABL  0.500 BLK      MULTICONDUCTOR Multiconductor  4
CABL 150C TXL 0.500 BLU LT   XLPE THIN  CABLE   1
SLEV     ID=0.24  OD=0.34 L=1.04 CLR    SLEV    2
TERM 6 F 6.3 DFK AG TERMINAL    3
```

If a simple weight value won't work, then you you'll have to set up a second table of excluded key words that you left join too.   Then only keep the ones that don't match.

Comment: It's overkill for the problem in hand and not a succinct as other solutions. IMO.

Comment: Yes, it's better cfg or large number of classifications.   This approach is far more configurable than a case statement and may be a better fit for the OP's "many other" classifications that he didn't mention.  If there truly are only the 7 or so that they listed then the case statement Gordon proposed is a far better solution.  I'd also argue there is value in the ability this solution provides to find records that match multiple keywords in combinations they might not have realized existed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a priority system for the types, so take advantage of the fact that `case` expressions are evaluated in order:

```
(CASE WHEN Descrip LIKE '%MULTI%' THEN 'MULTI'
      WHEN Descrip LIKE 'CABL%' THEN 'CABLE'
      WHEN Descrip LIKE '%SLEV%' THEN 'SLEV'
      ELSE '???!!!'
 END)
```